# OpenMP and STL vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, vector, openmp

I've got some code for which I'd like to use OpenMP in the following way:

```
std::vector<int> v(1000);
# pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    v[i] = i;
}
```

I have read that STL vector container is not thread-safe in the situation where multiple threads write to a single container, which would imply that I'd need to lock the vector before making any writes; however, I've also been told that the write operation above is somehow "atomic", and so there is no race condition above.  Could someone clarify this?

Comment: Check for concurrent_vector which allows multiple reads, writes

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In this particular example, it will be safe.

The reason is that you are not using operations that could cause a reallocation. (such as `push_back()`). You are only changing the contents of the individual elements.

Note that you can just as legally do this:

```
std::vector<int> v(1000);
int *ptr = &v[0];

# pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    ptr[i] = i;
}
```

---

It becomes not-thread-safe when you start calling methods like `push_back()`, `pop_back()`, `insert()`, etc... from multiple threads.

I'll also add that this particular example isn't well-suited for parallelism since there's hardly any work to be done. But I suppose it's just a dumbed-down example for the purpose of asking this question.

Comment: "not modifying the vector itself" -> "not using operations that could cause reallocation". But +1 anyway.

Comment: @larsmans Yes, that's a better wording that what I used. :) I'll change that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple reads are safe but I would recommend to avoid multiple writes to the same container. But you can write to memory you manage on your own. The difference to a vector would be that you can be sure that the memory would not be changed or reallocated at the same time. Otherwise you can also use a semaphore but this would probably decrease the efficiency and if you use several it can even cause deadlocks if you don't work properly.